# Can google Analytics track a unique users that using our app

Tags: google-analytics

I'm new when using google analytics for App and it make me quite confused, I have several question that I want to ask:

1. Is Google Analytics still track unique users? some of source that I read say no but and some say yes I'm quite confused about this
2. Let say if I want to search a Unique users can I use `User Type` dimension with `users` metric to get the right value for new users (**Not with session but users**)

for question number 2, let say it have `New Users` and `Returning Users` as `user Type` dimension and `users` have a metric and from google analytics itself give an explanation such as this:

> Users who have initiated at least one session during the date range. Learn more about how Analytics calculates the number of users.

Can someone help me to understand this? I'm already using it for 2 weeks and still confused with this

Answer (score 0):

By default, Google Analytics track unique users by setting an unique id ([clientId](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cookies-user-id?hl=en)) in device memory (a cookie in web tracking). This method isn't accurate because cleaning a cookie or device cache would reset clientId, causing the tool to identify a new user in the next session. To avoid it you can collect **[User Id](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123662?hl=en&ref_topic=3123660)**, a built-in dimension specific to user tracking.